# android studio Installation failed

Tags: android, android-studio

creating multiple project files, and at some point, when I start running emulators, The emulator is not working with the error message.
All the other project files I've created since this message came up, and it doesn't move.
but The pre-message project files work fine.

> Installation did not succeed.
> The application could not be installed.
> List of apks:
> [0] 'C:\Users\0902a\AndroidStudioProjects\2017019307_SeoJeongWoo_3week\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
> Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t -S 1684583' returns error 'Unknown failure: Binder driver could not be opened.  Terminating.''

what's the problem??

Answer (score 0):

You can try these two workarounds:-

1:- Try deleting avd's from **C:\Users\Shivam Bansal.android\avd**

2:- Try deleting the Android Studio cache from **C:\Users\Shivam Bansal.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches**

Try it with your location, mine was mentioned above.

Comment: try delete everything in caches? so appreciate for your answer

Comment: They will be auto generated once you open the project again.